# Cookie EU script clashing with other Wordpress plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've been rolling out a cookie eu law script on all our websites. All has worked fine until I got to this website:

http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/

For some reason it just will not load. I think it's clashing with a plugin. Can someone have a look?

This is what Wordpress has output in the head:

```
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>National Health Service market access &amp; entry - UK HealthGateway UK HealthGateway</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/themes/default/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/xmlrpc.php" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/themes/default/cookie_law.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').cwAllowCookies(); 
    });

</script>


<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.1.5 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="Selling to the UK National Health Service is challenging and time consuming. UK HealthGateway gives you the solutions and services to quickly and cost-effectively win sales."/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="9topKAjyLtAge98viaRrfR2QaeQEAdHk4WI_aMDlD-Q" />
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="UK HealthGateway &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="UK HealthGateway &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/comments/feed/" />

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    // Google Analytics for WordPress by Yoast v4.2.3 | http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount','']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    //]]></script>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="UK HealthGateway &raquo; Home Comments Feed" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/home/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jigoshop_frontend_styles-css'  href='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/assets/css/frontend.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jqueryui_styles-css'  href='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/assets/css/ui.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jigoshop_fancybox_styles-css'  href='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/assets/css/fancybox.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nivoStyleSheet-css'  href='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/nivo-slider.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nivoCustomStyleSheet-css'  href='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/custom-nivo-slider.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-style-css'  href='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/resources/events.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/assets/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/assets/js/jigoshop_frontend.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/assets/js/script.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/resources/jquery.pjax.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/resources/events.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.ukhealthgateway.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".nivoSlider br").each(function(){ // strip BR elements created by Wordpress
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'random,fold,fade,sliceDown'
            // All effects:
            // sliceDown, sliceDownLeft, sliceUp, sliceUpLeft, sliceUpDown
            // sliceUpDownLeft, fold, fade, random, slideInRight,
            // slideInLeft, boxRandom, boxRain, boxRainReverse, boxRainGrow
            // boxRainGrowReverse
            animSpeed:500, //Slide transition speed
            pauseTime:6000,
            startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
            directionNav:true, //Next & Prev
            directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
            controlNav:false, //1,2,3...
            controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, //Use image rel for thumbs
            controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...
            controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src
            keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
            pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering
            manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
            captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
            beforeChange: function(){},
            afterChange: function(){},
            slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>

</head>
```

UPDATE:
I've had a go at doing what you suggested (removed jQuery 1.4.2, moved cookie script so it loads after Nivoslider and changed $ to jQuery). It still doesn't load. For instance, I'm using exactly the same script on teamworksdesign.com and it works fine. The difference seems to be, that site uses Wordpress 3.1.3 whereas the site in my question uses 3.3.1. It also works on IE7 but not on modern browsers.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I've tried it in all different places but it still doesn't kick in. There should be a yellow bar appear at the top of the page.

Comment: I removed my last comment because you've changed the site. But it looks now like the problem is something somewhere is calling `noConflict`. Change your `$` call to use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I changed that as well but it doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: @Teamworksdesign.com Make sure that you include the relevant code from your site on Stack Overflow. Otherwise, this question should be closed as "Too Localised", because the answer would be useless once you update the site with the "working" code.

Comment: @RobW It won't let me as it's too much code hence the link. I think answers will help someone such as jquery versions clashing etc etc

Comment: @Teamworksdesign.com - You should post the specific code that is causing the problem. But chances are it's a problem with the plugin you're using. The plugin code doesn't look great... at first glance I see references to W3Schools and the use of `live` (which is deprecated)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like you've inserted your code straight into the head.  The jQuery library that came with your Wordpress install is being enqueued further down the page (version 1.7.1) so you don't need to add jQuery 1.4.2 as well.  That might be it.

If not it might be worth enqueuing your cookie script properly in functions.php along with your other scripts (jQuery UI and Nivoslider are being enqueued there). As James Allardice mentions, you could then add your

```
$('body').cwAllowCookies();
```

to the onload script that is setting up the Nivoslider just before the closing head tag, it's using jQuery() rather than $().

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer. I've had a go at doing what you suggested (removed jQuery 1.4.2, moved cookie script so it loads after Nivoslider and changed $ to jQuery). It still doesn't load. For instance, I'm using exactly the same script on http://www.teamworksdesign.com and it works fine. The difference seems to be, that site uses Wordpress 3.1.3 whereas the site in my question uses 3.3.1.

Comment: It is actually all working (in a snese).  If you check the code in Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug you'll see that the JS is successfully adding all the correct code to the DOM.  The reason it's not displaying is because the display: is set to none for .cwcookielaw .cwcookiesmoreinfo { }.  It's nothing to do with the WP version I would suggest, but to double check disable your plugins one by one.

Comment: It the exact same code as used on other sites which works perfectly so guessing it is a plugin/wp. Just trying to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

There are *some* apache security modules that look for filenames containing cookie.js and they do not serve the file.

I've had this problem on Drupal and i found [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/522646) that documented it.

Comment: I've got it working on another website using Wordpress that has a slightly different set of plugins so it's a plugin that's causing the issue somewhere.

Comment: Is the other site hosted on the same server? If not it may still be like i said.